# Inserting records to MSAccess

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Can someone explain to me why it wont allow me to insert my record into MS Access?
for some reason i have tried everything that is humanly possible but it wont let me do what i need to do. what i need to do is allow record to be written from my c Sharp program and would want to press a button which will insert the value into my MS Access.

```
void Insert_Record(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =BookCSharp.accdb";
    string dbcommand = "INSERT INTO BookKey, Title, Pages from Books;";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);          

    conn.Open();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "Books");

    conn.Close();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    //define a new record and place it into a new DataRow
    DataRow newRow   = dt. NewRow();
    newRow["BookKey"] = txtBookKey.Text;
    newRow["Title"]  = txtTitle.Text;
    newRow["Pages"]  = txtPages.Text;

    //add the new DataRow to DataTable 
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

    //update DB
    adapter.Update(ds, "Books");

    //accept changes
    ds.AcceptChanges();

    //update listBox1
    lstDisplayBooks.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        lstDisplayBooks.Items.Add(row["BookKey"] + " " + row["Title"] + " (" + row["Pages"] + ")");
    }
    txtBookKey.Enabled = false;
    txtBookKey.Text = " ";
    txtTitle.Enabled = false;
    txtTitle.Text = " ";
    txtPages.Enabled = false;
    txtPages.Text = " ";
    btnInsert.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you define the PK column? IIRC Access doesn't support Identity columns

Comment: Would it be humanly possible to post the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, they are supported. Access calls them "AutoNumber".

Answer (score 0):

An [OleDbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) need a SELECT query and an [OleDBCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate automatically the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands that will be used in the Update method

```
void Insert_Record(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =BookCSharp.accdb";
    string dbcommand = "SELECT * FROM Books;";
    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection))
    using(OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn))
    {
         OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
         OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
         // See comments below for these properties
         builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
         builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
         conn.Open();            
         adapter.Fill(ds, "Books");

         DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
         DataRow newRow   = dt. NewRow();
         newRow["BookKey"] = txtBookKey.Text;
         newRow["Title"]  = txtTitle.Text;
         newRow["Pages"]  = txtPages.Text;
         dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
         builder.GetInsertCommand();
         adapter.Update(ds, "Books");
    }

    //update listBox1
    lstDisplayBooks.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        lstDisplayBooks.Items.Add(row["BookKey"] + " " + row["Title"] + " (" + row["Pages"] + ")");
    }
    txtBookKey.Enabled = false;
    txtBookKey.Text = " ";
    txtTitle.Enabled = false;
    txtTitle.Text = " ";
    txtPages.Enabled = false;
    txtPages.Text = " ";
    btnInsert.Enabled = false;
}
```

The example in the link for the OleDbCommandBuilder contains an example like this.

The code should fix your initial error, but really there is no need to use an OleDbDataAdapter in this scenario. If your only objective is just to add a new record to the datatable and you don't need to maintain a local datasource like a DataGridView it is a lot simpler to use directly the OleDbCommand with an appropriate written INSERT and parameterized query

```
void Insert_Record(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =BookCSharp.accdb";
    string dbcommand = "INSERT INTO Books (BookKey, Title, Pages) VALUES(?,?,?);";
    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection))
    using(OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn))
    {
         conn.Open();            
         comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtBookKey.Text);
         comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtTitle.Text);
         comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtPages.Text);
         comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    .....
```

Comment: Thank you downvoter, you let me revise this question with more attention, however, really, there is no problem to leave a comment with observations on why you think this code is wrong. I think that is an act of courtesy to express your own opinion.

Comment: Good answer, but sample code for using an OleDbCommandBuilder with an Access database really should include `builder.QuotePrefix = "[";`  and.`builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";` because Access SQL has so many reserved words that can cause errors if used as column or table names.

Comment: Yes @GordThompson you are right, the OleDbCommandBuilder doesn't define these two properties and leave them empty. So the risk to have reserved keywords not quoted in the autogenerated commands is real. On the contrary, the SqlCommandBuilder defines automatically these two properties as you say. This make sense because the OleDb cannot know if these properties are different between the various database systems supported